# How am I getting values for routeParams, path and search without injecting $routeParams or $location?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Please see a sample code below:

```
var app = angular.module("sampleroute", ["ngRoute"]);    
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "main.htm",
            controller: "mainCtrl"
        })
        .when("/page/:type", {
            redirectTo: function (routeParams, path, search) {
                console.log(routeParams);
                console.log(path);
                console.log(search);
                return "/";
            }
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo:"/"
        });
    //console.log(routeParams, path, search);
});
```

The following code prints out 3 values for routeParams, path and search when routed to "/page/types?test=testValue". So this works without any issue.

My question is without injecting `$routeParams`, I am getting the value of  `routeParams` and without injecting `$location` I am getting the value of `path` and `search`.

How is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the angular documentation, it states:

> If redirectTo is a function, it will be called with the following
>   parameters:
>
> {Object.} - route parameters extracted from the current
>   $location.path() by applying the current route templateUrl.
>
> {string} -current $location.path()
>
> {Object} - current $location.search()

Angular is doing this behind the scenes for you.  That is why you don't need to inject $location or $routeParams directly.

Here is a link to the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: oops! You are right! I missed that out ... Thanks @nweg :)